# Sublime Text - Modifying tmTheme file

Tags: themes, sublimetext3, color-scheme

In the `.tmTheme` file:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Entity name</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>entity.name - (entity.name.filename | entity.name.section | entity.name.tag | entity.name.label)</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#A6E22E</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The next scope string:

```xml
<string>entity.name - (entity.name.filename | entity.name.section | entity.name.tag | entity.name.label)</string>
```

Is a kind of regular expression? What applies with this definition? In another part of the same file I can see something like this:

```xml
<string>variable.parameter - (source.c | source.c++ | source.objc | source.objc++)</string>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a regular expression; it's a [scope selector](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selectors.html) which was [borrowed from TextMate](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/introduction-to-scopes/).

> it's possible to AND, OR, and subtract scope selectors, e.g.: `(a | b) & c - d` would select the scope which is not matched by d, and matched by both c, and a or b.

In Sublime Text, you can find the scope of the character to the right of the cursor by going to `Tools` menu -> `Developer` -> `Show Scope Name`.

---

For testing selectors, you can use the `view.match_selector` or `view.find_by_selector` [APIs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html) in the Sublime Text console (`View` menu -> `Show Console`).

Example to see if the scope at the first cursor matches the selector from your first example:

```py
view.match_selector(view.sel()[0].begin(), 'entity.name - (entity.name.filename | entity.name.section | entity.name.tag | entity.name.label)')
```

---

### Operators

These are boolean logic operators:

- `-`: "not," used anywhere in the selector (to be clear, this is a dash surrounded by spaces, as a dash can appear in the middle of a scope name)
- `&`: "and," used anywhere in the scope (in a `.tmTheme` file, which is XML, the `&` should be escaped to `&amp;`, unless inside a CDATA node.)
- `|` and `,`: "or," used anywhere in the scope
- `(`…`)` can be used to group selectors together

There is also a hierarchical operator:

- (<kbd>space</kbd>): "after," must come after (i.e. to the right of) the preceding scope.

  - This does not work after a `(`grouping`)`.

### Notes

- Scopes should only ever consist of alpha numeric characters and dots (`.`), therefore conflicts with the operators will never occur.
- Scopes are separated by a single space.
- Whitespace around the operators are not necessary. (Whitespace is trimmed/stripped before evaluation.) i.e.  `string | comment`  is the same as `string|comment`.
- Leading and trailing dots are also stripped from scope selectors before they are evaluated
- Consecutive whitespace is treated as a single space.
- All scopes are split by `.` and matched from the beginning for as many levels as your selector has. `a.b` will match `a.b.c.d`.
- There are no wildcard operators in scope selectors. Therefore, you cannot match the scope `source.python` using `.python` or `*.python` etc.
- A completely empty selector matches everything. But not when followed by an operator. i.e. `|` on its own will fail, as will `|source`. `source|` works, however. `-` and `source -` will fail.
- If you are not sure about operator precedence, enclose parts of the expression in parentheses to make it clear. Remember to use an operator *other than space* after grouping, or the scopes directly after the grouping will be ignored.

### Example

In the following Python snippet, using the [syntax test format,](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) all the tests will pass, and thus it serves as a demonstration of how selectors work:

```py
a = "hello world" # comment
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string.quoted.double
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string.quoted
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string.quoted.
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - quoted.double
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string - comment
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string, comment
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string | comment
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string & - comment
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string & - comment
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ source string
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ source & (string - comment)
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ source - (string & comment)
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ string & source
#   ^ source.python string.quoted.double.block.python punctuation.definition.string.begin.python
#   ^ source & string & punctuation.definition.string.begin.python
#   ^ string & punctuation & source
#   ^ string punctuation & source
#   ^ source punctuation & string
#   ^ source string punctuation - (punctuation string)
#   ^ string - source comment - punctuation source
#   ^ string - source comment - comment
#   ^ source - python
#   ^ source - (source & python)
#   ^ source - (source python)
#   ^ source.python - source.python.string
#   ^ source.python.. ..string..
#                 ^ comment - string
#                 ^ comment
#                 ^ comment, string
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ comment, string | source
#   ^ (punctuation | string) & source.python - comment
#   ^ (punctuation & string) & source.python - comment
```

Note that due to how [scope selector specificity](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/08/syntax-highlighting-optimizations#_parent-selectors) seems to ignore some of the more advanced constructs, you might find that `.tmTheme` rules you create with scope selectors apply or don't apply in cases you might not expect.

Comment: Thanks for your link, so to mark off the meaning of my question:  
"Update: Starting with 1.1b17 it's also possible to AND, OR, and subtract scope selectors, e.g.: (a | b) & c - d would select the scope which is not matched by d, and matched by both c, and a or b."