# How to add space to both ends of a equal-sign when not in parentheses with specified file types?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is it possible? For example, When in `.py` and `.lua` file, not in `()` and I type `=`, st3 will automatically add a space to both ends. such as a assignment statement:

```
a = 1
```

But it is disabled if in a `()` state:

```
func(a=1) 
func(a=1,func(b=1))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by creating a keybinding on the <kbd>=</kbd> key, to insert a space, followed by the `=` and another space, that will check:

- that the syntax at the caret corresponds to Python or Lua
- that the text between the beginning of the line and the text caret contains no unbalanced brackets

If the conditions are not met, the keybinding is not used, and `=` will be inserted without surrounding whitespace as normal. (Assuming other keybindings on the `=` key, if any, are evaluated and found not to apply.)

---

## Steps

1. In Sublime Text, open the `Preferences` menu and select `Keybindings - User`.
2. If the document is not empty, move the text caret to after the first `[` character at the beginning of the document.
3. Paste in the following:

   ```
   { "keys": ["="], "command": "insert", "args": { "characters": " = " }, "context":
       [
           { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
           { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python, source.lua", "match_all": true },
           { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^(([^()]*+)(\\((?:(?2)|(?3))*\\))?+)(?1)*+$", "match_all": true }
       ]
   },
   ```
4. If the document was previously empty, type a `[` at the beginning of the document, and a `]` at the end of the document.  This is to ensure that it is a valid JSON array.
5. Save the file.
6. Press the <kbd>=</kbd> key in a Python or Lua document, and see that it will automatically insert spaces around it when not inside unbalanced parens.

---

### Explanation of the regex:

This aspect of Sublime Text uses the [PCRE regex flavor provided by the Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html), which supports recursion, and thus allows us to not have to repeat ourselves to determine whether the brackets are balanced or not.

- `^` start of the line
- `(` begin capture group 1

  - `([^()]*+)` - possessively capture every consecutive non-parenthesis character into capture group 2
  - `(` begin capture group 3

    - `\(` match a literal `(` character
    - `(?:(?2)|(?3))*` recursively match the same regex pattern that corresponds to capture group 2 or 3 (i.e. recursive), zero or unlimited times
    - `\)` match a literal `)` character
  - `)` end capture group 3
  - `?+` make the previous group optional but possessive
- `)` end capture group 1
- `(?1)*+` possessively recursively match the same regex pattern that corresponds to capture group 1, zero or unlimited times
- `$` end of the text to be matched - in this case, where the text caret is, because the `preceding_text` context is used.

The overall effect is that is will match where any of the following are true on the line where the text caret is, before the caret position:

- no parens are used
- non-nested parens are opened and closed
- nested parens are all closed
- there are no closing parens that don't have a corresponding open paren

Because the regex is being stored in JSON, the `\` characters need to be escaped with an extra `\`, which is why the `operand` string contains `\\(` but I only refer to `\(` in the regex explanation.

### Scope Selector

To ensure that the keybinding is only active on Python and lua, the scope `selector` context is used, with an argument of `source.python, source.lua`. This selector matches either `source.python` or `source.lua`, or indeed both together if such a thing were possible to embed one language in the other.

One way to find what the base scope of a language in Sublime Text is, would be to go to the very beginning of a document set to the relevant syntax, and go to the `Tools` menu -> `Developer` -> `Show Scope Name`. It will even work on an empty file.

Scope selectors are borrowed from TextMate, and more documentation on them can be found here:

- [TextMate docs](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/introduction-to-scopes/)
- [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37407588/4473405)

#### Keybinding Documentation

More information about keybindings can be found here: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#structure-of-a-key-binding

I personally find it useful to view the default keybindings for inspiration.